# SSO com IIS: Autenticação Interna e Externa

Tags: php, iis, sso

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo uma melhoria na autenticação, no qual implementamos o SSO internamente e o formulário padrão externamente.
Utilizamos ZF3, porém não consigo 2 tipos de autenticação num mesmo site do IIS (mesma porta).

Gostaria de uma ajuda para contornar este problema, algum membro poderia me ajudar?

Aguardo e agradeço a oportunidade.